# Dos dígitos en el printf de un entero

Tags: c, printf

Tengo un problema, y es que me gustaría que el resultado mostrado en un `printf` siempre se vean 2 cifras al representar un entero, por ejemplo:

- Si introduzco `8` quiero que se muestre `08`
- Si introduzco `25` quiero que se muestre `25`
- Si introduzco `0` quiero que se muestre `00`

Esto lo estoy tratando de hacer para pasar de `minutos` al formato típico de `hh:mm`.
Dejo por aquí mi código, el cuál funciona correctamente, únicamente necesitaría la parte del `printf` que indica que se muestren siempre 2 dígitos (en caso de que sea posible).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t hh = 0;
    uint8_t mm = 0;
    uint32_t minutos = 0;

    scanf("%d", &minutos);

    hh = minutos/60;
    mm = minutos - 60*hh;

    printf("Minutos: %d\n", minutos);
    printf("Tiempo: %dh:%dm\n", hh,mm);

    return 0;
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indicando un número antes de la `d`, quiere decir que quieres introducir ese número de caracteres. Si el número a imprimir es más pequeño se introducirán espacios, si el número es más grande, entonces aparecerá el número entero: `printf("%2d", numero);`

Para que aparezcan ceros en lugar de espacios, hay que poner un cero delante del número de caracteres: `printf("%02d", numero);`

Prueba con esto:

```c
int a = 8;
int b = 24;
int c = 0;

printf("%02d\n%02d\n%02d", a, b, c);
```

El resultado será:

```
08
24
00
```

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias ;)

Answer (score 1):

Facil, después del `%` introduce la secuencia `02`:

- `0` este primer caracter indica cual será el *relleno*, es decir, el caracter que se usará para rellenar los espacios restantes
- `2` es el ancho del campo

Es decir:

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    printf("%02d", i);
}
```

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias ;)